# how to stop ring server started using ring.util.serve

Tags: clojure, ring

I am starting my server in the repl using

```
(use 'ring.util.serve)
(serve my-app/handler)
```

How do I stop the server once started using it.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ring.util.serve` also contains `stop-server` which can be used to stop the server. So this should work for you:

```
(stop-server)
```